# PhpStorm Remote Development

Tags: phpstorm

I am interested in evaluating PhpStorm. I am currently a VSCode user but want tighter integration with my PHP development.

The only feature I see that might be a show stopper is not having a Remote Development feature. A lot of the codebases I work on do not reside on my local machine.

Does PhpStorm currently have this option? Specifically, this has proven to be very beneficial in my day to day operations: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh

Does PhpStorm have remote development built into it?

Comment: It is not exactly a remote development but it is possible to edit files remotely (actually, you edit a local copy and IDE uploads it back transparently):
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/accessing-files-on-remote-hosts.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhpStorm doesn't have this Remote Development (with SSH) feature currently.
Though you could use it to edit remote files directly with SSH: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/editing-individual-files-on-remote-hosts.html but debugging, refactorings, and some other IDE features are not supported for such files.

We do consider supporting the workflow for full remote development support, when you're having sources in one place, building them in another and opening an editor in the third one, but we do not have particular plans to share or ETAs for it, sorry.
Please watch this feature request here for update notifications: [IDEA-226455](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-226455).

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE 2023: PHP storm have SSH remote development by Jetbrain Gateway. Select "File" > "Remote development"